# Adding audio files to a playlist being currently played in Windows Media Player from command line

Tags: command-line, windows-media-player

I started Window Media Player via the command line (actually from a C# application using Process.Start) and provided one file name. Now Windows Media Player establishes a new Playlist consisting of this one file and plays it.
Next, I'd like to add further files to this current playlist. When I call

```
public void OpenAudioFile(string path)
{
    string wmPlayerPath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe");
    Process.Start(wmPlayerPath, $"/Play {path}");
}
```

again, Windows Media Player just replaces the file being played instead of adding the new file to the list.

What's the correct command to do so?
(There must be one - how else could that be a context menu in Explorer?)

Edit:
I found out that I can create a playlist by providing several filenames at once, e.g.

```
    public void OpenAudioFiles(IEnumerable<string> paths)
    {
        string wmPlayerPath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe");
        string args = "";
        foreach (string path in paths)
        {
            args = args + " " + $"\"{path}\"";
        }
        Process.Start(wmPlayerPath, args);
    }
```

That's a workaround for many cases, but not for all cases.

Comment: Are you actually talking about the command interpreter, or your C# application? Because those are two different things.

Comment: Also, there being a context menu extension for WMP does not mean there is a command line method. It means there's code the application has linked to the appropriate places in the system to allow this command to be initiated from the context menu. The closest you'll find for being able to hook into this yourself would be through an API, not a set of command line utilities.